# Angular ngFor not rendering the item in the array, but the array renders fine using array[index]

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm encountering a weird problem for a very straightforward program. I have a list of number array to display. If I use *ngFor, the elements in the array will not render. However, if I literally display the element using array[0], array[1], etc, it works fine.

Here is what I've tried -
A property is declared in the component ts.

`quantities: number[] = [1,2,3,4];`

In the Html template,

`{{ quantities[0] }}` is rendering fine, but below *ngFor is not. It shows only the bullet point without any text.

`<ul><li *ngFor="let q of quantities">{{ q }}</li></ul>`

EDIT:
I found the problem happened when I'm trying to render the array inside a ngIf block. See below. If I moved the unordered list block outside the ngIf block, the numbers are rendered fine. But when it's inside the ngIf block, it's not rendering (but test[0] works).

```
<div *ngIf="test.length > 0; else empty">
{{ test[0] }}
<ul><li *ngFor="let q of test">{{ q }}</li></ul>
</div>
<ng-template #empty>empty message</ng-template>
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? I just pasted your code to a clean StackBlitz example and was not able to reproduce this.

Comment: What happens when you wrap `{{test[0]}}` inside a `<div *ngIf=“true”></div>`? Small chance this is to do with the way angular checks templates. Sometimes how nested a binding is *within the same template* matters.

Answer (score 0):

you can see this link in my stackblitz ,
it works fine (try to restart the server)
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-94aewh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html